# Getting null values when reading in JSON file in eclipse using java

Tags: java, json, eclipse, string

I am reading in a JSON file that I put in my project folder.  I am not getting an error that the file doesn't exist and before I added the line to ignore unknown values I was getting errors.  So I am pretty sure it is reading values in.  The problem I am having is when I try to print out variables from the JSON file I get null values.

```
File jsonFile = new File("FoodItemData.json");
    FoodItemData food = null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    try {
        food = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, FoodItemData.class);
        System.out.println(food.getcountry());
        System.out.println(food.getId());
        System.out.println(food.getDescription());
        System.out.println(food.getcountry());
        System.out.println(food);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(food.getcountry());
```

I call the class FoodItemData and it returns null for all the gets.

```
public class FoodItemData{
private String country;
private String category;
private String description;
private String id;
private String name;
private String price;

public String getcountry(){
    return this.country;
}
public void setcountry(String country){
    this.country = country;
}
public String getCategory(){
    return this.category;
}
public void setCategory(String category){
    this.category = category;
}
public String getDescription(){
    return this.description;
}
public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}
public String getId(){
    return this.id;
}
public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPrice(){
    return this.price;
}
public void setPrice(String price){
    this.price = price;
}
```

}

Here is my JSON file

```
    { "FoodItemData": [
  {
    "-country": "GB",
    "id": "100",
    "name": "Steak and Kidney Pie",
    "description": "Tender cubes of steak, with tender lamb kidney is succulent rich gravy.  Served with a side of mashed potatoes and peas.",
    "category": "Dinner",
    "price": "15.95"
  },
  {
    "-country": "GB",
    "id": "101",
    "name": "Toad in the Hole",
    "description": "Plump British Pork sausages backed in a light batter.  Served with mixed vegetables and a brown onion gravy.",
    "category": "Dinner",
    "price": "13.95"
  },
  {
    "-country": "GB",
    "id": "102",
    "name": "Ploughman’s Salad",
    "description": "Pork Pie, Pickled Onions, Pickled relish Stilton and Cheddar cheeses and crusty French bread.",
    "category": "Lunch",
    "price": "10.95"
  }
]
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit and add the content of your json file

Comment: most likely you have a mismatch between your `FoodItemData` and what you have in the FoodItemData.json file. Posting a content of that file will help to see if this is a case

Comment: @user1631616 I changed the name of the Java file from FoodItemData to just FoodItem, it still get a null value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Jonathan pointed out instead of having an object inside of `FoodItemData.json` file you actually have a `Map` with single key and an array as value. So the minimum what you can do is this (using `Gson` lib `com.google.gson.Gson`) in order to read the content of the file:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("./FoodItemData.json")));
    Map<String, List<FoodItemData>> object = (new Gson()).fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<Map<String, List<FoodItemData>>>(){}.getType());
    List<FoodItemData> data;
    if (object.values().iterator().hasNext()){
        data = object.values().iterator().next(); // this is you data in your case 3 FoodItemData entries
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    ....
}finally{
    if (reader != null) {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that once you do this, because in your json file country starts with `-` it will not get in

Answer (score 1):

Your file contains a `FoodItemData[]`, not a FoodItemData (see also http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp and search for arrays). This array obviously misses all of the properties of the FoodItemData and the resulting object returns `null` for all properties. At the same time disabling FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES leads to no exceptions when trying to make a FoodItemData from it.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more, I have been playing around with FoodItemData as an array and am still getting a null return value