# Null values after reading data from rest API

Tags: java, json, gson

Have similar problem to this but i couldnt work this out [Getting null values when reading in JSON file in eclipse using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822779/getting-null-values-when-reading-in-json-file-in-eclipse-using-java)
I'm having problem while reading data from this https://runsignup.com/Rest/races?format=json&country=US

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        final String racesUri = "https://runsignup.com/Rest/races?format=json&country=US";
        HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient
                .newBuilder()
                .proxy(ProxySelector.getDefault())
                .build()
                .send(Request.requestGet(racesUri), HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        RaceList races = gson.fromJson(response.body(), RaceList.class);
        System.out.println(response.body());
        System.out.println(races);
```

I just want to get "race_id" and "name" Race class looks like this:

```
package stefanowicz.kacper.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Race {
    private long race_id;
    private String name;
}
```

Responsy body is perfectly fine but when im trying to convert it to the RaceList object which look like this:

```
package stefanowicz.kacper.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class RaceList {
    private List<Race> races;
}
```

And every Race has "race_id" equaled 0 and "name" as null.

RaceList(races=[Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null), Race(race_id=0, name=null)])

Comment: You are missing an object level (class) between `RaceList` and `Race`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your classes should look something like this:

```
public class RaceList {
    private List<Race> races;
}

public class Race {
    private RaceData race;
}

public class RaceData {
    private long race_id;
    private String name;
    /* ... */
}
```

The name of the first race should then be accessed as `races.getRaces().get(0).getRace().getName()` if `races` is the name of the variable holding the `RaceList` object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, your answers have lead me to, i hope so, best solution:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class RaceList {
    private List<Map<String, Race>> races;
}
```